# How to communicate with JAX-WS based SOAP webservice from java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I searched google, but i cant find a way to do this. I have a SOAP webservice built in netbeans with JAX-WS . Gerated wsdl cannot be accessed by my java client code. Is the way i am trying to access is wrong? someone help..

my web service code

```
@WebService(serviceName = "HolaMundo") 
public class HolaMundo { 

@WebMethod(operationName = "hello") 
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) { 
return "Hello " + txt + " !"; 
} 
}
```

generated wsdl

```
<!-- 
 Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2-hudson-740-. 
--> 
<!-- 
 Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2-hudson-740-. 
--> 
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://publicar.ws.org.mx/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://publicar.ws.org.mx/" name="HolaMundo"> 
<types> 
<xsd:schema> 
<xsd:import namespace="http://publicar.ws.org.mx/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8084/HolaMundo/HolaMundo?xsd=1"/> 
</xsd:schema> 
</types> 
<message name="hello"> 
<part name="parameters" element="tns:hello"/> 
</message> 
<message name="helloResponse"> 
<part name="parameters" element="tns:helloResponse"/> 
</message> 
<portType name="HolaMundo"> 
<operation name="hello"> 
<input wsam:Action="http://publicar.ws.org.mx/HolaMundo/helloRequest" message="tns:hello"/> 
<output wsam:Action="http://publicar.ws.org.mx/HolaMundo/helloResponse" message="tns:helloResponse"/> 
</operation> 
</portType> 
<binding name="HolaMundoPortBinding" type="tns:HolaMundo"> 
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/> 
<operation name="hello"> 
<soap:operation soapAction=""/> 
<input> 
<soap:body use="literal"/> 
</input> 
<output> 
<soap:body use="literal"/> 
</output> 
</operation> 
</binding> 
<service name="HolaMundo"> 
<port name="HolaMundoPort" binding="tns:HolaMundoPortBinding"> 
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8084/HolaMundo/HolaMundo"/> 
</port> 
</service> 
</definitions>
```

Java client code

```
public class cliente { 
    public cliente() { 
    } 

    public static String consumir(Object[] parametros){ 
        String regresar = null; 
        Service service = null;    
        Call call       = null; 
        String endpoint = null; 
        try { 
          endpoint = "http://localhost:8084/HolaMundo/HolaMundo";          
          service = new Service(); 
          call = (Call) service.createCall(); 
          call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint)); 
          call.setOperationName("hello");          
          regresar=String.valueOf(call.invoke(parametros));          
        }// try 
        catch (Exception e) { 
          e.printStackTrace(); 
        }// catch 
        finally { 
          return regresar; 
        }// finally 
      } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        try {            
            String parametro = "José"; 
            String respuesta = consumir(new Object[]{parametro}); 
            System.out.println("respuesta: --->" + respuesta); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.err.println(e.toString()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

but i am getting the error

```
AxisFault 
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client 
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Cannot find dispatch method for {}hello 
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
   {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Cannot find dispatch method for {}hello
```

help me. thanks

Comment: try using wsimport(part of JDK). it will generate the client side artifacts for you. once genereted, code is as simple as "HolaMundo_Service service = new HolaMundo_Service();  HolaMundo port = service.getHolaMundoPort();String response = port.hello("Anton");". if you print the response, it will say 'Hello Anton !'.

Comment: it creates lot of code which is same like the web service! can you suggest me the dynamic way of calling SOAP operation ?

Comment: did you mean wsimport takes a lot of code?

Comment: did you mean wsimport generetes lot of code? yes, it does.But not much and reduces your effort to a great extend.